# How to take IP range from console and make requests to all IPs within range using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ip, uri, range

I want to take IP range like 192.168.1.10-40 from console and want to make request to each IP and print responses on console.

Is this possible to do this using net/http and uri or one needs something else?

Comment: What have you tried? Especially, what have you tried to parse that user input to a sensible format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making a few assumptions of the syntax of your IP-ranges I ended up with the following. You might want to consider taking two full IP-addresses or [CIDR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825928/netmask-to-cidr-in-ruby) instead.

```
require 'ipaddr'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

range = ARGV[0]
from, part = range.split("-")
arr_from, arr_part = from.split("."), part.split(".")
to = (arr_from.take(4-arr_part.length) << arr_part).join(".")

puts "HTTP responses from #{from} to #{to}"

ip_from = IPAddr.new(from)
ip_to = IPAddr.new(to)

(ip_from..ip_to).each do |ip|
  puts ip.to_s
  begin
    puts Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse("http://#{ip.to_s}/") )
  rescue => e
    puts e.message
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be even nicer if it supported input like `192.168.1.1-255.255`, like by using `part = part.split('.'); to  = (from.split('.')[0...part.size] + part).join('.')`

Comment: Updated the answer so that it parses `192.168.1.1-255.255` and alike.

Comment: above code works but if it times out to some IP address in between it wont proceed further on next one in range.what to do for that?

Comment: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

The IPAddr class includes Comparable, so you can do things like:

```
require 'ipaddr'
(IPAddr.new("192.168.1.10")..IPAddr.new("192.168.1.40")).each{|ip| puts ip}
```

Comment: That does not answer any of the questions.

Comment: Actually, it answers "can I take a range of IP and do <something> on them?"

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: Not even that. The difficulty about that wouldn't be how to generate the IP range, but how to parse input like `192.168.1.10-40` or `192.168.1.1-255.255` correctly.

Comment: got your point but I want to inject header in request I make for each IP and then want to print all using $stdout. I wrote like this bu getting error:`puts "StartIP:\n\n" startip = gets() puts "EndIP:\n\n" endip = gets() (IPAddr.new("#{startip}")..IPAddr.new("#{endip}")).each do |address| range = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(address.to_s)) range.initialize_http_header("Origin" => "#{originip}") range.set_debug_output($stdout) response = http.range range end`

Answer (score 0):

Addition to [steenslag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9348996/479558) answer.

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'ipaddr'

(IPAddr.new("192.168.1.10")..IPAddr.new("192.168.1.40")).each do |address|
  puts Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://#{address.to_s}"))
end
```

UPD: added `http://`

Comment: And where exactly does this parse the input? I think that this would be the actual difficulty about it.

Comment: Doesn't this answer the question? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How to parse something like `192.168.1.10-40` or `192.168.1.1-255.255` into an IPAddr range? That is the difficulty (and OP doesn't seem to have made any effort to solve this himself, so this is not a good question).

Comment: just like steenslag answered - change ip addresses there and that's all.

Comment: "I want to take IP range like 192.168.1.10-40 from console". Did you actually read the question?

Comment: If the question is about "how to parse command line arguments" then it should have been asked differently. The question is how to make requests for range of IP adresses.

Comment: The question is about 1. how to read and parse an IP range 2. how to "request" to each IP. It's totally unclear what's meant by that second part and there seems to be no effort to solve this, so I voted to close.

Comment: got your point but I want to inject header in request I make for each IP and then want to print all using $stdout. I wrote like this bu getting error:`puts "StartIP:\n\n"
startip = gets()
puts "EndIP:\n\n"
endip = gets()
(IPAddr.new("#{startip}")..IPAddr.new("#{endip}")).each do |address|
  range = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(address.to_s))
  range.initialize_http_header("Origin" => "#{originip}")
  range.set_debug_output($stdout)
  response = http.range range
end`